# Heroku: how to scale to multiple workers

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

I just paid for a Hobby account on Heroku. It says I'm allowed up to 7 worker dynos. How do I turn on more than one dyno?

This is my Procfile:

```
web: node app.js
worker: node worker.js
```

I tried to scale the workers with the command:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=3
```

But I got this error message:

```
! Cannot update to more than 1 Hobby size dynos per process type.
```

Comment: My mistake - Heroku only allows 1 Hobby size dynos per process type. i.e. I can't have multiple worker processes.

Comment: It's confusing tho, on the pricing page hobby says "MULTIPLE WORKERS FOR MORE POWERFUL APPS"

Comment: Yeah, I don't get what 10 process types does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=1`

more details: [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#scaling-a-process-type)